# How to change title text on navigation of component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a React project, I have two Navbars one SideNavbar and other BottomNavbar. When navigating through SideNavbar title text changes with specific component but, BottomNavbar doesn't. The BottomNavbar navigates correctly but, title text doesn't change.

TopNavbar

```
const TopNavbar = () => {
  const itemList = [ 
    {
      text: 'Home',
      icon: home,
      link: "/"
    },
    {
      text:  'Gallery',
      icon: photos,
      link: `/contents/lists/${sessionStorage.getItem('bucketIdPhoto')}`
    },
    {
      text: 'Videos',
      icon: videos,
      link: `/contents/lists/${sessionStorage.getItem('bucketIdVideo')}`
    },
    {
      text: 'Celebyte',
      icon: celebyte,
      link: "/celebyte"
    },
    {
      text: 'Direct Line',
      icon: directLine,
      link: "/directLine"
    },
    {
      text:  'Video Call',
      icon: videoCall,
      link: "/videocall"
    },
    {
      text:  'Invite A Friend',
      icon: inviteAFriend,
      link: "/invite"
    },
    {
      text:  'Settings',
      icon: settings,
      link: "/settings"
    }
  ]
  
  const classes = useStyles();
  const classes2 = useStyles2();

  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    left: false
  });

  const [data, setData] = useState('')

  const toggleDrawer = (anchor, open) => (event) => {
    if (event.type === 'keydown' && (event.key === 'Tab' || event.key === 'Shift')) {
      return;
    }

    setState({ ...state, [anchor]: open });
  };

  const list = (anchor) => (

    <div className={classes2.root}>
        <ArrowBackIcon onClick={toggleDrawer(anchor, false)} />
    <div
      role="presentation"
      onClick={toggleDrawer(anchor, false)}
      onKeyDown={toggleDrawer(anchor, false)}
    >
      <List>
        <Link to="/profile">
        <ListItem>
        <div className={classes.root}>
        <Grid container spacing={2}>
         
          <Grid item xs={8}>
               <div style={{display:'flex', flexWrap:'wrap', width:'140%'}}>
               <img src={sessionStorage.getItem('imageData')} style={{borderRadius:'50px', height:'50px'}} />
               <span style={{display:'flex', flexWrap:'wrap'}}>
                 <img src={fan} height="18px" style={{marginTop:'6px'}} />
                 <ListItemText primary={sessionStorage.getItem('nameData')} secondary={sessionStorage.getItem('emailData')} />
               </span>
               </div>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={4}>
                  <img src={rightArrow} style={{float:'right'}} />  
          </Grid>
         
        </Grid>
        </div>
        </ListItem>
        </Link>

        <Divider />

        <Link to="/wallet">
        <ListItem>
        <div className={classes.root}>
        <Grid container spacing={3}>
          
          <Grid item xs={6}>
              <ListItemText primary="Account Balance" />
              <span style={{display:'flex', flexWrap:'wrap'}}>
              <img src={armsprimeCoin} height="28px" />
              <h1 style={{fontWeight: 'bold',fontSize: '30px',marginLeft: '5px'}}>{sessionStorage.getItem('coinsData')}</h1> 
              </span>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
               <img src={rightArrow} style={{float:'right'}} />
               {/* <ChevronRightIcon style={{float:'right'}} /> */}
          </Grid>
         
        </Grid>
        </div>
        </ListItem>
        </Link>
      </List>

      <List>
        {itemList.map((item, index) => {
          return (

            <ListItem button key={item.text} onClick={() => {setData(item.text)}}>
                  {item.icon &&  <img src={item.icon} style={{marginRight:'25px'}} height="18px"  />} 
                  <NavLink exact to={item.link}  >
                      <ListItemText primary={item.text} />  
                  </NavLink>
            </ListItem> 

          )})}
      </List>
    </div>

    </div>
  );

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static" style={{background:'white'}}>
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton edge="start" className={classes.menuButton} color="inherit" aria-label="menu">
          {['left'].map((anchor) => (
                <>
                  <Button onClick={toggleDrawer(anchor, true)} >
                      <MenuIcon style={{ color: '#8e44ad', fontSize:'2.5rem' }} />
                  </Button>
                  <Drawer anchor={anchor} open={state[anchor]} onClose={toggleDrawer(anchor, false)}>
                    {list(anchor)}
                  </Drawer>
                </>
                ))}
          </IconButton>

          {/* Here the title is changed on Navigation */}
          <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
            {data == '' ? 'HOME' : data.toUpperCase()}
          </Typography>
          <IconButton
                    aria-label="account of current user"
                    aria-controls="menu-appbar"
                    aria-haspopup="true"
                  >
                    <AccountCircle style={{fontSize:'30px'}} />
        </IconButton>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TopNavbar
```

BottomNavbar

```
const BottomNavbar = () => {


  const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);


  const itemList = [
    {
      text: 'Home',
      icon: home,
      link: "/"
    },
    {
      text:  'Gallery',
      icon: photos,
      link: `/contents/lists/5cda8e976338906c6a279712`
    },
    {
      text: 'Videos',
      icon: videos,
      link: `/contents/lists/5cda8ebe6338906cbe7ce252` 
    },
    {
      text: 'Celebyte',
      icon: celebyte,
      link: "/celebyte"
    },
    {
      text: 'DirectLine',
      icon: directLine, 
      link: "/directLine"
    },
    {
      text: 'VideoCall',
      icon: videoCall,
      link: "/videocall"
    },
    {
      text: 'MyProfile',
      icon: profile,
      link: "/profile"
    }
  ]

  return (

    <GridList className={classes.gridList}>
       {itemList.map((tile) => {
        return <GridListTile key={tile.icon} style={{height:'70px', width:'20%'}}>
           <ListItem button key={tile.text}>
           <NavLink exact to={tile.link} activeClassName="main-nav-active" style={{textAlign:'center'}}>
                 {tile.icon &&  <img src={tile.icon} height="25px" style={{marginTop:'10px'}} />}  
                 <ListItemText disableTypography
       primary={<Typography style={{fontSize:'10px',fontWeight:'bold', fontFamily:'Nunito' }}>{tile.text}</Typography>} />
             </NavLink>
           </ListItem>
         </GridListTile>
       })}
      
    </GridList>
  );
}

export default BottomNavbar
```

How to change title text from BottomNavbar? Any appropriate solution highly appreciated

Following is the codesanbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/9vrc1

Comment: Because your title's state is on TopNavBar you have two choice, 1. use useLocation + useEffect to detect location changed and from location.pathname find the correct title. Or 2. Share title's state by redux or context.

Comment: I tried to use first solution [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-material-forked-5sftg) but your videos and photos links are dynamic.

Comment: @navand Thanks... its working perfectly... for photos and videos I've to put some logic in it